# Regex search for word in column using variable inside regex, return matched word and variable name

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Basically I'm trying to get the regex matched word + the word from the loop on the same row of the DataFrame if that makes sense.

I've tried creating lists from column names and zip through but that didn't work. I'm also not sure how to use a variable name in the re.findall with regex, otherwise I'd try something like:

```
result = pd.DataFrame()
for word in file2:
   x = re.findall(word.*, file1)
result = result.append(x, word)
```

I know the above doesn't work, and there is probably a few reasons why, I'd really love some explanation as to why the above mock code wouldn't work and how to make it work... Meanwhile, I came up with the below, which HALF works:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import read_csv

file1 = pd.DataFrame(read_csv('alldatacols.csv'))
file2 = pd.DataFrame(read_csv('trainColumnsT2.csv'))

new_df = pd.DataFrame()

for word in file2['Name']:
    y = file1['0'].str.extractall(r'({}.*)'.format(word))
    new_df = new_df.append(y, ignore_index=True)
new_df.reset_index(drop=True)
print(new_df)
print(new_df.columns)
```

result::::::::::

```
0                       Id
1               MSSubClass
2         MSZoning_C (all)
3              MSZoning_FV
4              MSZoning_RH
5              MSZoning_RL
6              MSZoning_RM
7              LotFrontage
8                  LotArea
9              Street_Grvl
10             Street_Pave
11              Alley_Grvl
12              Alley_Pave
13            LotShape_IR1
14            LotShape_IR2
15            LotShape_IR3
16            LotShape_Reg
17         LandContour_Bnk
18         LandContour_HLS
19         LandContour_Low
20         LandContour_Lvl
21        Utilities_AllPub
22        Utilities_NoSeWa
23        LotConfig_Corner
24       LotConfig_CulDSac
25           LotConfig_FR2
26           LotConfig_FR3
27        LotConfig_Inside
28           LandSlope_Gtl
29           LandSlope_Mod
..                     ...
266               PoolArea
267              PoolQC_Ex
268              PoolQC_Fa
269              PoolQC_Gd
270            Fence_GdPrv
271             Fence_GdWo
272            Fence_MnPrv
273             Fence_MnWw
274       MiscFeature_Gar2
275       MiscFeature_Othr
276       MiscFeature_Shed
277       MiscFeature_TenC
278                MiscVal
279                 MoSold
280                 YrSold
281           SaleType_COD
282           SaleType_CWD
283           SaleType_Con
284         SaleType_ConLD
285         SaleType_ConLI
286         SaleType_ConLw
287           SaleType_New
288           SaleType_Oth
289            SaleType_WD
290  SaleCondition_Abnorml
291  SaleCondition_AdjLand
292   SaleCondition_Alloca
293   SaleCondition_Family
294   SaleCondition_Normal
295  SaleCondition_Partial
```

Example output I'm looking for:

```
17         LandContour_Bnk      LandContour
18         LandContour_HLS      LandContour
19         LandContour_Low      LandContour
20         LandContour_Lvl      LandContour
274       MiscFeature_Gar2      MiscFeature
275       MiscFeature_Othr      MiscFeature
276       MiscFeature_Shed      MiscFeature
277       MiscFeature_TenC      MiscFeature
281           SaleType_COD      SaleType
282           SaleType_CWD      SaleType
283           SaleType_Con      SaleType
284         SaleType_ConLD      SaleType
285         SaleType_ConLI      SaleType
286         SaleType_ConLw      SaleType
287           SaleType_New      SaleType
288           SaleType_Oth      SaleType
289            SaleType_WD      SaleType
290  SaleCondition_Abnorml      SaleCondition
291  SaleCondition_AdjLand      SaleCondition
292   SaleCondition_Alloca      SaleCondition
293   SaleCondition_Family      SaleCondition
294   SaleCondition_Normal      SaleCondition
295  SaleCondition_Partial      SaleCondition
```

Please help me understand how to get this over the hump. Thank yoU!

Answer (score 0):

So I just made another DataFrame that got populated by me searching for just the word, without the .*. Then I concatenated both DataFrames and got what I needed... that was a simple solution I couldn't think of for the last 7 hours while I tried other approaches

```
file1 = pd.DataFrame(read_csv('alldatacols.csv'))
file2 = pd.DataFrame(read_csv('trainColumnsT2.csv'))

new_df = pd.DataFrame()
**df = pd.DataFrame()**
for word in file2['Name']:

    y = file1['0'].str.extractall(r'({}.*)'.format(word))
    **x = file1['0'].str.extractall(r'({})'.format(word))**
    new_df = new_df.append(y, ignore_index=True)
    **df = df.append(x, ignore_index=True)**

new_df.reset_index(drop=True)
**df.reset_index(drop=True)
result = pd.concat([new_df, df], axis=1)**

result.to_csv('result.csv')
```